# Nativescript shared schema in VSCode always redlines classes with error "experimental support for decorators..." error

Tags: typescript, nativescript, visual-studio-code, angular2-nativescript

I've tried everything, reloaded, allowJS, switching between the values of these two:

`"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
 "experimentalDecorators": true,`

in tsconfig.json and adding it to tsconfing.tns.ts as well. Turning plugins off, uninstalling them outright, nothing seems to work!

The error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tinkering with it again I found that vscode needs to enable the 'ability to turn it on or off' in order to care about whatever we write in the tsconfig.json.

Turn the ability to use this setting by just searching in your vscode > preferences for 'experimental decorators' and check that box.